# Sqlite Local database is not accurate

Tags: android, database, sqlite, local

I'm developing android application and I'm storing some data in the local database using sqlite. When I save the database from the device file explorer and browse it using DB browser for sqlite it shows many records there which are correct. BUT i have implement a function that count number of records for specific table and it returns 0 which is wrong value.

I'm lost now cause I think the function  is correct

```
public int numOfRecords(String tableName) {

    int numOfRecords = 0;
    try {

        String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName ;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            numOfRecords = cursor.getInt(0);
        }

        db.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex ) {
        Log.d("test" , "In exception");
    }
    return numOfRecords;
}
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger to check you don't catch any exception ?

Comment: I think you must be hitting your exception handler. Update the exception handler to be `Log.e` instead of `Log.d` as you'll be able to filter on error. Append the error from the exception object as well to your log output, e.g. `Log.e("test", "In Exception: " + ex.getMessage());`

Comment: @ArthurAttout Yes , it doesn't catch any exception so the function works correctly I just don't know what I'm messing here

Comment: @Boardy thank you for your response , but it didn't catch any exception

Comment: Might be worth including the code where you add records to the database as there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your function to get the number of records

Comment: Most likely you are not querying the database that you copied. Your app created a new database with empty tables.

Comment: I found out that it's returns 0 cause I have uninstall the app then run it again and I forgot that. But I thought when I uninstall the app the data in the local database should be removed as well but it's not , it's still there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
public long getProfilesCount() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    long count = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_NAME);
    db.close();
    return count;
}
```

Or

```
public int getProfilesCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Hits , I tried both of them all returned 0 value

Comment: I think data not stored in DB please check first.

Comment: I found out that it's returns 0 cause I have uninstall the app then run it again and I forgot that. But I thought when I uninstall the app the data in the local database should be removed as well but it's not , it's still there.